# Possible Blind SQL Injection Fault found in wp-ajax.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

Need a suggestion/help for how to apply a workaround to the issue SQL injection found in my WordPress site. I was googling but still couldn't find a proper solution for the same problem.

Vulnerable URL: `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=search1&searchval=--9999`

Ideally it should not return any result but I'm getting following responds.

[image: Screen shot that shows responds]

**WP Version:** version 5.0.3

**Server:** Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS8

Comment: Are you using prepared statements to fetch your queries from the database?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for your comments. 
I was able to solve it by adding an integer value validation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, just for this one parameter `searchval` would be to check if it's a numeric value using `is_numeric()` php built-in function.